# SoapClient Class does not return response object data

Tags: php, soap

I have this code, with others services works fine but in one service this class dont return any data.

If I use the __getLastResponse method, the class return XML string, but i need the object data.

```
$options = array('trace' => 1,'use' => SOAP_LITERAL); 

$soapclient = new SoapClient('http://webservice.host.fantasy/Service/Foto?wsdl', $options);
$res = $soapclient->TramFoto(['id' => '01065']);

print_r($soapclient->__getLastResponse());
```

Comment: What happens, if you remove the `use` option? Do you get a response in this case? Is it necessary that this option is used?

Comment: No, remove USE and the function __getLastResponse() dont respone anything.

Comment: What is the content of `$res` when you remove the `use` option?